# GoogleAPIs for Node.js, how to oauth2 user on server without a browser and human interaction

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api

The problem:

I am creating simple backend only app that will check some things on my google calendar account. I want it to run one api call once a week.

Calendar api requires oAuth2 usage. All examples I found require human interaction flow:

1. run method
2. server asks user to open browser on special url and copy code displayed there
3. user does that and pastes code into console
4. server validates it and saves token to some file
5. server executes calendar api call

The problem with this is I don't want to do this every week. I want it to auth once and then run unattended.

One way would be to set token exp date to over 1 week and then refresh it with each call. But that could not recover connection in some cases (power loss for example).

What I tried so far:
I obviously started [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs). It worked but I had to use browser.

Then I found [google-auth-library-nodejs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs). But that defaults to JWT which then does not work with calendar. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong:

```
private async initApiKey() {
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const calendar = await google.calendar({version: 'v3', client});
    const events = await calendar.events.list({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
      maxResults: 10,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
    });
    return client;
  }
```

`google.calendar` should be passed oauthclient and here `client` is JWTClient. I guess I could force oAuth but it would force browser (it even uses opn).

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make requests on behalf of a user (even your own user) you must obtain an oauth token.

JWTokens are used for service accounts, which are not actual users and do not have calendars. These accounts perform API actions on behalf of a Google Cloud Project or other type of object.

The purpose of OAuth is for the user to provide explicit consent to allow API interactions on their behalf by a server registered to an application with google. You'll need to OAuth via a browser to obtain a token. The refresh token can be used much later to keep this token fresh. You can store those tokens and refresh after a power loss or other restart event.

Comment: Ok, I see. What are the dangers that could prevent token refresh and sever the connection ?

Comment: There’s probably a limit on how long the refresh token is good for—that information would be in the docs. It’s typically long enough for you to not have to do it more than once per day—it could even be good for as long as a week. I’m not sure.